# Каким образом принимать решения о выборе правильного варианта перевода?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, термины

Задавая вопрос сообществу о терминах, в какой-то момент, так или иначе, нам  следует принять один из предложенных вариантов перевода.

Каким же образом принимать решения о выборе того или иного вариант перевода для термина, особенно, если по результатам голосования нет явного фаворита? Какими критериями и правилами следует руководствоваться? В каких случаях? Есть ли исключения из этих правил?

Comment: Предлагаю тут метку [meta-tag:faq], а сам вопрос - в новый пост про изменения. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как мне кажется, можно поступать следующим образом.

- Публикуется вопрос.
- Если у автора есть соображения по теме, он публикует каждое отдельным ответом.
- Другие пользователи добавляют свои решения.
- Сообщество голосует за ответы.
- По прошествию не менее чем суток с момента публикации, если лидер голосования определился, вопрос должен быть принят автором, а результат [добавлен в глоссарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1135/181472).
- Автору следует руководствоваться результатами голосования и здравым смыслом, конечно же.

Если вопрос не будет принят автором в оговоренное время, модератор берет право принятия решения на себя.

Comment: Сутки — мало. Как показывает практика, мы гораздо дольше голосуем (пример — Community или системные метки). Кстати, ссылка на hashcode битая. Не знаю, на что ее заменить.

Comment: Поправил битую ссылку и несколько поменял инструкцию.